# if exist command is not working in batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have one file at c:\1\1.txt

In my batch program before performing any operation I have to check whether the file exists or not

My command is

```
If exist c:\1\1.txt
 Echo 1
```

Its not working. In fact, because of if command the batch is crashing.

Answer (score 4):

read `HELP IF` and then try

```
IF EXIST c:\1\1.txt ECHO 1
```

note that you have to put the `IF` command, the condition, and the conditional command instruction in the same line

alternatively you can use parentheses

```
IF EXIST c:\1\1.txt (
  ECHO 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I have used this code, written in `batch.bat`:

```
@ECHO OFF

If exist c:\1\1.txt ECHO 1
```

Please, specify "bash is crashing".

Answer (score 0):

test in reverse CONDITION using NOT

```
If NOT exist c:\1\1.txt EXIT

Echo EXIST
```

Answer (score 0):

first check by command console the name of file doing

```
cd c:\1
dir *.txt
```

why?

if you create a new file txt with notepad and save it writing in name field `1.txt`, the final file name is `1.txt.txt` , you can verify this with command console doing

```
cd c:\1
dir *.txt
```

then `if exist` sentence work fine because `1.txt` don't exist, the true name of file is `1.txt.txt`.

is a posibility for this problem.

Comment: valid point (depends on your computer settings), but the original problem ("crashing batch") was a syntax error with the `if` command.